# How import file Excel to multiple tables in DB using asp.net and angularJS?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have developed an application, and in this application I want to import file Excel to multiple table in my DB, and since i am a beginner in angularJS and .NET,  I work with .net web api and angularjs, and I develop a function, it works when I import the data into a singe table, but the problem how to import the data into 3 table in DB !!! . and the 3 tables are linked to each other (in my exemple code there 2 table `Candidature` and `Candidat`). My question is: how to import Excel file to multiple table in DB and thank's. ( i work with asp.net web API and angularJS )

controller.cs:

```
/////
 [Route("api/Candidature/SaveData")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Candidat))]
        public IHttpActionResult SaveData(List<Candidature> Candidatures, List<Candidat> candidat)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            foreach (var data in Candidatures)
            {
                db.Candidature.Add(data);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var data in candidat)
            {
                db.Candidat.Add(data);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);

////
```

service.js:

```
 SaveData: {
                method: 'POST' ,
                url: serviceBase + 'Candidature/SaveData',
                isArray: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            },
```

CandidatureCtrl.js :

```
  $scope.Importation = function (data) {
                $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = null;
                $scope.UploadFile = function (files) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () { //I have used $scope.$apply because I will call this function from File input type control which is not supported 2 way binding
                        $scope.Message = "";
                        $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = files[0];
                    })
                };
                //Parse Excel Data
                $scope.ParseExcelDataAndSave = function () {
                    var file = $scope.SelectedFileForUpload;
                    if (file) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var data = e.target.result;
                            //XLSX from js-xlsx library , which I will add in page view page
                            var workbook = XLSX.read(e.target.result, { type: 'binary', cellDates:true, cellStyles:true });
                            var sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
                            var excelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                            if (excelData.length > 0) {
                                //Save data
                                Candidature.SaveData(excelData).then(function (data) {
                                    if (data.status) {
                                        $scope.Message = excelData.length + " record inserted";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $scope.Message = "Failed";
                                    }
                                }, function (error) {
                                    $scope.Message = "Error";
                                });
                                // Candidature.SaveDatacandidature(excelData).then(function (data) {
                                //     if (data.status) {
                                //         $scope.Message = excelData.length + " record inserted";
                                //     }
                                //     else {
                                //         $scope.Message = "Failed";
                                //     }
                                // }, function (error) {
                                //     $scope.Message = "Error";
                                // });
                               // $scope.SaveData(excelData);
                            }
                            else {
                                $scope.Message = "No data found";
                            }
                        }
                        reader.onerror = function (ex) {
                            console.log(ex);
                        }
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                    }
                };
                var dialogOpts = {
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    scope: $scope,
                    size: 'lg',
                    templateUrl: 'views/candidature/Importation.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance','$sce',
                        function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $sce) {

                            $scope.cancel = function () {
                                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                            };
                        }
                    ]
                };
                $uibModal.open(dialogOpts);

            };
```

Importation.html :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.1/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/jszip.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="app/views/candidature/candidatureCtrl.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="agu">
    <div ng-controller="candidatureCtrl" class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control"
                   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().UploadFile(this.files)"/>
            <input type="button" value="Import" class="btn btn-success"  ng-disabled="!SelectedFileForUpload"
                   ng-click="ParseExcelDataAndSave()" />
            <br/>
            <span style="color:red">
                {{Message}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web api, you are expecting two arrays for `Candidatures` and `candidat`.

But from your controller you are passing only one array of data `excelData`.

So when it comes to api it doesn't execute this code,

```
foreach (var data in candidat) 
{
    db.Candidat.Add(data); 
}
```

Because **candidat** is either `null` or `undefined`. So it can't go through the loop which the below code is never executed.

> db.Candidat.Add(data);